# Изменения значения select в зависимости от значения input

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Есть 1 `input` и 1 `select`, как сделать так, что бы в `select` выводилось значение в зависимости от того, что было ведено в `input`. Напримет, вот количество баллов по предмету 100, вводим 100 в `input`, и в `select` должно вывести **Отлично**. Эти таблицы есть в  базе данных. Понимаю, что надо через `ajax`, но не получается.

Comment: А что не получается? Приложите код, так сложно ответить на вопрос.

Comment: Отправляете данные через аякс, на сервере проверяете баллы, в ответ отправляете словесное значение этих баллов, а на клиенте перегружаете select новыми данными, где нужный option имеет св-во selected.

Comment: ajax вам для решения этой задачи не нужен. Просто устанавливайте value select'a при событии change input'a.

Answer (score 1):

Более элегантно

```js
var keys = {
  rates: [
    {name: "very-bad", begin: 0},
    {name: "bad", begin: 25},
    {name: "normal", begin: 50},
    {name: "good", begin: 75},
    {name: "very-good", begin: 100}
  ]
}
  var select = document.getElementById("sel");

document.getElementById("rate").addEventListener("input", function(){
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (keys.rates[i].begin <= this.value) select.value = keys.rates[i].name;
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="sel">
  <option value="very-bad">Очень плохо</option>
  <option value="bad">плохо</option>
  <option value="normal" selected>Средне</option>
  <option value="good">хорошо</option>
  <option value="very-good">Очень хорошо</option>
</select>
<input type="number" id="rate" min="0" max="100" value = "50">
```

Comment: спасибо) но у меня почему то нечего не меняет почему-то. я даже пробовал создал новую страницу и закинул ваш код, но тоже нечего не происходит

Comment: получилось, но чисто для новой страницы. А лично для моего кода ,  то нет. так как инпутов у меня много и я так понимаю , взять по айди не получится, можно ли взять по классу?

Answer (score 0):

Набросал для вас пример кода на jQuery:

```
<select name="select" id="select">
  <option value="bad">Не очень</option>
  <option value="normal">Нормально</option>
  <option value="good">Отлично!</option>
</select>

<input type="number" min="0" max="100" name="numberInput" placeholder="Введите число" id="numberInput">

<script>
$('#numberInput').on('input', function () {
    var val = $(this).val(),
        $select = $('#select');

    if (val >= 0 && val <= 40) {
        $select.val('bad');
    }

    if (val > 40 && val <= 60) {
        $select.val('normal');
    }

    if (val > 60 && val < 100) {
        $select.val('good');
    }
});
</script>
```

Обратите **внимание**, что код выше не предусматривает валидацию, элегантность и т.п.

Comment: спасибо) тоже почему-то нечего не меняет, тоже пробовал создать новую страницу и закинуть тупо туда код ваш, но закинул и нечего не меняет